# Query multiple insights metrics in one API call

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

Is it possible to query more than one insights metric in one API call?

For example to get the daily added likes for a page I executed the following call:

https://graph.facebook.com/_object_id_/insights/page_fan_adds_unique/day/

But I would like to have another metric, e.g., page_fan_removes_unique, included as well.

Query the insights object entirely is a possibility, but gives me too much data I don't need, thus decreases performance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can run a multiple FQL query in one API call and then parse the various results.

multi query: http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/rest/fql.multiquery/

insights table: http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/fql/insights/

Comment: FQL is no longer supported beyond version 2.0. Also, the multiquery link is dead.

Comment: both links look dead now, would have been nice to include some info here rather than just pasting a link

Answer (score 2):

Since your question shows that you're using the Graph API, you may want to use the batch requests method:  http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/batch/

You can group multiple Graph API queries together so you can just query the Insights data you need in one request.