# How can I query multiple object insights in one Facebook API Call?

Tags: facebook, api, rest, facebook-graph-api

I saw this question ([Query multiple insights metrics in one API call](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8818169/query-multiple-insights-metrics-in-one-api-call)) but their answers are from 2012 and no longer work.

I want to get `post_video_avg_time_watched` and `post_video_views` in a single api call to Facebook.

How is this possible?

I don't want to use Facebook's batch request, because it counts against my rate limits twice instead of once.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, and easily! Just add the second value after a comma and the first value like so: `/insights/post_video_views,post_video_avg_time_watched/lifetime`